# Use sum function in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-fusion-apps

I'm working with oracle fusion and one of the apps I'm working with (value-sets) does not allow me to use functions in the select statement and the from section has a 200 character limit.

This query gives me what I want but I cant use the sum with the select-

```
SELECT SUM(d.ABS_UNITS) from PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F b, ANC_ABSENCE_PLANS_F_TL c, 
ANC_PER_ABS_PLAN_ENTRIES d
WHERE 
d.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID
AND c.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID = d.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID
AND c.name = 'FMLA LWOP'
and d.start_date between '2017-04-02' and '2017-04-15'
AND b.PERSON_NUMBER = p_num
```

I also tried this but had the character limit issue -

```
Select aa.bb from
(SELECT SUM(d.ABS_UNITS) as bb from PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F b, 
ANC_ABSENCE_PLANS_F_TL c, ANC_PER_ABS_PLAN_ENTRIES d
WHERE 
d.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID
AND c.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID = d.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID
AND c.name = 'FMLA LWOP'
and d.start_date between '2017-04-02' and '2017-04-15'
AND b.PERSON_NUMBER = p_num
) aa
```

This approach is what I've been trying to work with putting the sum in the where clause but it's not returning anything.

```
Select
d.ABS_UNITS
FROM
PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F b, ANC_ABSENCE_PLANS_F_TL c, ANC_PER_ABS_PLAN_ENTRIES d
WHERE 
d.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID
AND c.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID = d.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID
AND c.name = 'FMLA LWOP'
AND b.PERSON_NUMBER = pnum
and d.start_date between '2017-04-02' and '2017-04-15'
AND d.ABS_UNITS = (SELECT SUM(d.ABS_UNITS) from PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F b, 
ANC_ABSENCE_PLANS_F_TL c, ANC_PER_ABS_PLAN_ENTRIES d
WHERE 
d.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID
AND c.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID = d.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID
AND c.name = 'FMLA LWOP'
and d.start_date between '2017-04-02' and '2017-04-15'
AND b.PERSON_NUMBER = pnum
)
```

Any input and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need a `GROUP BY` with the `SUM` and need a `HAVING` clause, which acts as a `WHERE` for aggregated amounts.

Comment: I have not touch fusion apps.  Looking at the data model, it is not clear to me that you would want to sum ABS_UNITS. Have you tried creating a view of your query?

Comment: Does Oracle fusion support usage if WITH clause? if so, might be able to leverage that ?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a HAVING clause in the original:
SELECT SUM(d.ABS_UNITS) from PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F b, ANC_ABSENCE_PLANS_F_TL c, 
ANC_PER_ABS_PLAN_ENTRIES d
WHERE 
d.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID
AND c.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID = d.ABSENCE_PLAN_ID
AND c.name = 'FMLA LWOP'
and d.start_date between '2017-04-02' and '2017-04-15'
HAVING b.PERSON_NUMBER = p_num

Comment: Unfortunately HAVING and GROUP BY are also not available to me in this area.

Comment: @Patrick Bacon These are hours I need a script to check for an absence accrual rate. I'm trying to find an alternative to using a loop in the script because the run time is slow. Sum of the ABS_UNITS is what I'd like so I can evaluate a period versus a day at a time. But I have not explored the view approach maybe that will be available on the database end.

Comment: Were you planning on using bind variables for your dates or perhaps a sysdate offset block of time?

Comment: Yeah I'll be using bind variables for the dates. The accrual dates correspond to pay period dates.

Comment: Probably from gl_periods table or the fusion apps equivalence (I am thinking in terms of Oracle Apps R12 which has similarities).

Answer (score 0):

I have not work with fusion apps.
If I don't understand wrong you have limits for character limit and functions in select.

Your 'where' clause is long considering your character limit. You can shorten it using ALIAS for columns and tables in database level. Then customize your query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input I really appreciate it. I found a work around, Oracle Fusion has hidden functions in the script language I was working with that are not documented but can be found through sql. Very frustrating, but thanks for all the feed back

Comment: what was the workaround  ? @ranger.dan

Answer (score -1):

You can't use aggregate functions (such as `SUM`) in `WHERE` clause, because `WHERE` limits rows physically. You shall aggregate in `GROUP BY` clause to logically limit output.

Comment: but you can limit using "having clause" if there are aggregates in his select list

Comment: Did I say something in contrary to your comment or my answer is wrong? The heading of question says "Use sum function in where clause", I suggested how to use aggregate correctly.